# Which attribute is used for increasing row/cell height in NatTable?

Tags: eclipse-rcp, nattable

Which config attribute should be used to increase row height of a NatTable?
Is there any attribute to set in the config registry? or is there any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using DataLayer#setDefaultRowHeight() sets the default row height for all rows, if not a row height is set for a special row via DataLayer#setRowHeight(int, int)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `DataLayer` class `setDefaultRowHeight()` method.